# Use sql inner join/union to combine data from the same table

Tags: sql, join

I have a table called Registration with 4 fields in it. CandidateID, Date, AMPM, Register.

The data that is contained in the table is the following

```
123, 6/7/2014, AM, /
123, 6,7,2014, PM, \
125, 6,7,2014, AM, /
125, 6,7,2014, PM. P
123, 7,7,2014, AM, I
123, 7,7,2014, PM, \
124, 7,7,2014, PM, \
```

I have got a query which extracts the data out for each candidate ordering the latest date descending.

```
Select CandidateID, "Date", AMPM, Register
From Registration
WHERE CandidateID=CandidateID
ORDER BY "Date" DESC
```

However I would like to go one step further and join the results up by candidateID and date, so I get the following output.

```
123, 6/7/2014, AM, /, PM, \
125, 6,7,2014, AM, /, PM, P
123, 7,7,2014, AM, I, PM, \
124, 7,7,2014,   ,  , PM, \
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please, not certain whether to use inner join or union. I'm thinking I need to add  and AMPM="AM" into the Where clause to filter the morning, but then how do I get PM rows to appear on the same row.

Thanks all that respond

Comment: It is inclear, at least to me, what you mean by "one step further". Also what is the purpose of always true `CandidateID=CandidateID` condition?

Comment: Is the combination `CandidateID` `Date` `AMPM` unique?

Comment: No the CandidateID, Date and AMPM are not unique. This is a child table. The where clause is indeed wrong - I want to look at a specific registration for a candidate which lets say is 123.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
select A.CandidateID, A."DATE", A.AMPM, A.Register, B.AMPM, B.Register
from Registration as A
inner join Registration as B on A.CandidateID = B.CandidateID and A."Date" = B."Date"
  and A.AMPM = 'AM' and B.AMPM = 'PM'
```

Also: `full outer` join is necessary if there may exist row with `AM` without corresponding `PM` (or vice versa).

Comment: last value should be B.AMPM = 'PM'
Also, if the OUTER JOIN is required, then you may not get any values for A.CandidateId, A.Date, so you would need to check this using CASE A.CandidateID IS NOT NULL THEN A.CandidateID ELSE B.CandidateID AS CandidateID - same for the Date. this will be the case for 124 from the example set.

Comment: As for `PM` it was a typo - thanx. As for `outer join` I was simply waiting for more information from OP...

Answer (score 0):

As i gathered from you,

Select R.CandidateID,R.Date,R.AMPM,R1.AMPM,R.Register from Registration R join Registration R1
on R.CandidateID=R1.CandidateID and R.Date=R1.Date
order by R.Date desc

Let try and post how to need the output.

Answer (score 0):

Full OUTER JOIN query as suggested by @KubaWyrostek

```
select
 (CASE A.CandidateID IS NOT NULL THEN A.CandidateId ELSE B.CadidateId) CandidateId, 
 (CASE A."DATE" IS NOT NULL THEN A."DATE" ELSE B."DATE") RegisterDate,
 A.AMPM, 
 A.Register, 
 B.AMPM, 
 B.Register
FROM Registration A
OUTER JOIN Registration B ON A.CandidateID = B.CandidateID 
  and A."Date" = B."Date"
  and A.AMPM = 'AM' 
  and B.AMPM = 'PM'
ORDER BY RegisterDate DESC
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, unfortunately  the db I am using (FileMaker) uses a subset of SQL and doesn't support Full Outer Join and Right Joins. Im going to have to look at trying to achieve this via a script rather than SQL